# Find exact match in text file using a second text file as reference Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text, match

I want to search a text file for exact matches which are specified in a second text file. So for instance file 1 contains a text about fruits and text file 2 has the following words:

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
Peach
```

Now each line of file 1 should be searched if one of the above words appear. If so, it should be printed inluding the frequency how often it was found (as you can see duplicates should not be in the output):

```
Apple 2
Orange 5
```

For that purpose I've got the following code so far:

```
def search_terms():
    with open("searchterms.txt", "r") as st:
        search_terms = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in st]
    return search_terms

def exact_match(phrase, word):
    b = r'(\s|^|$)'
    return re.match(b + word + b, phrase, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

f = open("file_to_search.txt", "r")
searchstr = search_terms()
for line in f:
    for word in searchstr:
        if exact_match(line,word):
            print(word)
f.close()
```

One problem is that the file with the search terms has about 45k lines. Each line is one possible string to look for in the first file. For that reason the execution time is quite poor at the moment.

I guess there has to be a more efficient solution to do this. Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange for this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ As long as you don't have a specific question / problem it is probably better to ask there.

Comment: It would go a lot faster if you switch it around... That is read the file line by line, and match each line against the search terms. And as long as the search terms file is not to big, this could/should be read once and kept in memory, which would speed it up even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all lower case of all search terms in a set and change your code like this:

EDIT: To print Frequencies you can use dictionary

```
def search_terms():
    with open("searchterms.txt", "r") as st:
        search_terms = [line.rstrip('\n').lower() for line in st]
    return search_terms

terms = set(search_terms())
freq = {}
for line in f:
   for word in line.split():
       if word.lower() in terms:
           if word in freq:
               freq[word]++
           else:
               freq[word]=1
for word,frequency in freq.iteritems():
    print word,frequency
```

As documented [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), Checking `in` in a `set` would have an average time complexity of O(1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have two more questions: How would your code look like if I want it to print the frequency of each match next to the match itself (see question at the top)? And how can I make sure that the output won't contain any duplicates? I.e. 'Orange' won't be printed five times but just once with a frequency of 5.

Comment: @monpy Please edit your question and add your requirement

Comment: Thanks again. I've edited my question. Just one more thing: Is there a possibility to to update your code in such a way that also search terms with more than one word will be found, e.g. 'apple tree'?

Comment: @monpy please mark answer as correct if you got your answer :)

Comment: @monpy it depends on what you need. If this is just one word or two words you can check them using above code but for a phrase search you must search for Indexing and Full-Text Search terms.

Comment: I've just accepted your answer. Let's say my text and my file with the search terms contain 'apple tree' somewhere. Hence 'apple tree' should also be found and printed. Is this possible with your code?

Comment: @monpy my code is using hash method to increase the search speed. 'apple tree' is a two word phrase and not a word. To check for frequency of each two word phrase with this method you must iterate the lines again and this time after split check two consecutive words.